# kubectl patch yaml file not resource object

Tags: yaml, kubectl

Is there a way to patch a **yaml file** with kubectl patch?

So I mean not to patch a already deployed e.g. deployment with a json array but a file:

```
kubectl patch -f deployment.yaml -p '{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"test","image":"test"}]}}'
```

(Code snippet not working)

Or if this is not possible how to best practice manipulate a kubernetes yaml based on a json array?

Comment: Did you try to: `kubectl patch -f file.yaml -p 'JSON' --dry-run -o yaml > file.yaml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the help documents for `kubectl` you can see that it is not a supported feature:

```
$> kubectl patch -h
Update field(s) of a resource using strategic merge patch, a JSON merge patch, or a JSON patch.
```

Since files on your filesystem are not API resources. I personally believe the method method for manipulating Kubernetes manifests with [JSON patches](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) would be [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/).

Kustomize is an Overlay Engine. Similar to Helm, it is designed in a way that automates the deployment of software to Kubernetes. They differ, however, in how they do so. Where Helm would manage a list of variable files that are then injected into a template at runtime, Kustomize would instead perform a merge of a patch over a generic example file.

These patches can be defined in a couple ways. One of which is `patchesJSON6902`. [Here is an example](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/jsonpatch.md) of how one would do so.